# $A$ is countable if and only if exists a $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ surjective

Tags: functions

$A$ is countable if and only if exists a $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ surjective

My try:

$\Rightarrow$] If A is countable we can set a function $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ such that fill up A with a countable domain set. In other words, $\phi$ is surjective.

$\Leftarrow$] Como $\phi$ is surjective we can find its inverse image such that for all $a_j \in A$ we got $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} \phi(m_{i}) = a_j$ and because $\phi$ is surjective we can enumerate (count) the elements of $A$, this is, $A=\{a_1,a_1,...,a_k\}$

Comment: What is your definition of *countable*?

Comment: Should $A$ be assumed to be nonempty?

Comment: - A set $A$ is infinity countable if $A  \sim \mathbb{N}$  and - A set $A$ is countable if is finite or infinity countable

Comment: Your forward direction is incomplete. What is that function? It needs to be defined. What happens if $A$ is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is countable, so $A$ is either finite or countably infinite. If it is finite, say $A=$ $\{$ $a_1,a_2...,a_n$ $\}$ then define $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ by
$\phi(j)=a_j$ if $j=1,2...,n-1$ and $\phi(k)=a_n$ for $k\geq n$. Clearly this function is surjective. On the other hand, if $A$ is countably infinite then by definition, such a surjection exists. Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ is a surjection. You want to show that $A$ is countable (in fact the domain can be countable and this would still hold). Suppose $A$ is non-empty:

Let $f: A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be defined by declaring for each $a\in A$, $f(a)$ is the smallest $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\phi(n)=a$. This exists because $\phi$ is surjective and the well ordering principle. Observe that this map is well defined and furthermore is injective because if $f(a)=f(a')=n_1$ then $\phi(n_1)=a=a'$ ($\phi$ is well defined). Hence $A$ is either finite or countably infinite.

Note: I am assuming you have already proved that if $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective and $B$ is countable, then so is $A$.